# Calculus on Manifolds (Spivak) Problem 2-26 (a)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}\cdot e^{-(x+1)^{-2}},  & x \in (-1, 1) \\
0, & x \not\in (-1,1)
\end{cases}$$

I want to show that $f$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function.

I know that $g = \begin{cases} e^{-x^{-2}}, & x \neq 0 \\ 0, & x = 0 \end{cases}$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function. So I can write $f$ as $g(x-1)\cdot g(x+1)$ on $(-1,1).$ So $f$ is clearly infinitely differentiable on $(-1,1)$ [I can show this using the product rule for $n$th derivatives]. Since $f$ is constant outside of $[-1,1]$, it is infinitely differentiable there as well.

But how do i show differentiability at $-1$ or at $+1$?

Roughly, I would have to split the limit into one from the right and one from the left and translate $f$ to $g$, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Can someone help me out with this case?

Also is my reasoning solid in the other cases?

Comment: @florence but $f \neq g(x-1)g(x+1)$ for $|x| > 1$, which is exactly what OP is asking about...

Comment: Hint: Compute the derivatives of $g(x-1)g(x+1)$ at $x = \pm 1$ using the product rule. Observe that they are all zero. These are the values of one-sided derivatives of $f(x)$ at $x = \pm 1$. The other one-sided derivatives are also clearly zero since $f(x) = 0$ for $|x| > 1$. Thus the derivatives all exist at $x=\pm 1$

Comment: @Alex, since $f = g(x-1)g(x+1)$ on $(-1,1)$, we have $f^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} [g^{(i)}(x-1)][g^{(n-i)}(x+1)]$. But this only works for $(-1,1)$. How do I show these derivatives are continuous at $\pm 1$? Maybe induction might work?

Comment: From this I know that $\lim_{x \to -1^{+}} f^{(n)}(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^{-}} f^{(n)}(x) = 0$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Not exactly. Google "one-sided derivative."

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, and I think I got it. Assuming (for induction sake) that $f^{(n)}(1) = 0$, we get $f^{(n+1)}(1^{-}) = \lim_{h \to 0^{-}} (f^{(n)}(1 + h) - f^{(n)}(1))/h$ and writing $f^{(n)}(1+h)$ in terms of $g$ (and easily showing the right derivative is zero) completes the induction. Thanks!